# How to avoid or enable geography field in group by in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, group-by, spatial

How can I calculate the distance between the given Point and the database users.GeoLocation in the select statement. I need the group by clause (This query is simplified.). But SQL Server is complaining:

The type "geography" is not comparable. It cannot be used in the GROUP BY clause.

If I remove it from the group by clause it also complains.
What to do? Conversion to another field type somehow?

```
SELECT    geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326).STDistance(users.GeoLocation) AS distanceKM,                    
          users.ID
FROM      users_Users AS users
GROUP BY  users.ID,
          users.GeoLocation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just take out the GeoLocation column from the grouping, then calculate as a separate (sub)query.  For example:

```
DECLARE @fixedPoint GEOGRAPHY = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);

WITH UserGrouping AS
(
    SELECT
        // Other Columns
        users.ID
    FROM
        users_Users AS users
    GROUP BY
        users.ID
)
SELECT
    UG.*,
    users.GeoLocation.STDistance(@fixedPoint) AS distanceKM
FROM
    UserGrouping AS UG
    JOIN
    users_Users AS users ON (UG.ID = users.ID);
```